# rails and solr how to limit or set range for searchable attribute ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, range, limit

I have a Company model that has many industries and a level.

I've got a helper function that gets the number of industries based on the level.

Say a Company model instance with "Basic" level should only be searchable for the first 2 industries, although it might contain more, I only want it to show up in results for the first 2 industries.

In the model I have

```
searchable do
  integer :industry_ids, multiple: true
```

How do I limit the search for the model instance, so that only a specific number of industries can be searched for based on the level as determined by the num_of_industries helper function.

something like

```
searchable do
  integer :industry_ids[num_of_industries], multiple: true
```

EDIT:
I figured it out

```
LIMITED_INDUSTRIES_BASED_ON_LEVEL = {
  'Free' => 1,
  'Silver' => 3,
  'Gold' => 5,
  'Platinum' => 5
}
def industries_limited
  self.industries.limit(LIMITED_INDUSTRIES_BASED_ON_LEVEL[self.level])
end
searchable do
  integer :industry_ids, multiple: true do
    self.industries_limited.map(&:id)
  end
end
```

Comment: You talk of Company, level, industries like we know your requirements. Please add relevant details as we cannot assume them. Please provide a higher level overview of your problem and the schema of the thing in question.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out
Company's level is say "Free", and is thus limited to 1 industry, but it can add more, so in the future if it decides to upgrade, all of the information is there. So I was limiting the search itself to basically only count the industries based on the level (in this case only count the first 1, since for level = "Free", the limit is 1)

```
LIMITED_INDUSTRIES_BASED_ON_LEVEL = {
  'Free' => 1,
  'Silver' => 3,
  'Gold' => 5,
  'Platinum' => 5
}
def industries_limited
  self.industries.limit(LIMITED_INDUSTRIES_BASED_ON_LEVEL[self.level])
end
searchable do
  integer :industry_ids, multiple: true do
    self.industries_limited.map(&:id)
  end
end
```